# NeptunJs Installation on Google Blogger

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I've been trying to add this NetptunJS game emulator (java script) on my google blogger but it doesn't work, the developer claim that its made for all sites an bloggers (just copy and paste the code),Official website: http://neptunjs.xyz/doc.html
this is an example of the code:

```
<script>

var NepPlayer = "#emu";     // ID of html element where the emulator will be inserted
var NepEmu = "nes";         // Platform select
var NepZoom = "enable";     // Add extra button on toolbar to scale up emulator. Disabled by default
var NepMaxWidth = "1100px"; // Maximum width size of emulator. 870px by default
var NepLang = "en";         // Interface language of the emulator. EN by default
var gameUrl = "//neptunjs.xyz/roms/nes/Super Mario Bros (W) [!].zip"; // Game Url
<script>

<script
src="https://mem.neptunjs.com/njs/njsLoader.js"
type="text/javascript"> //NeptunJS lib
```

can anyone please give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The code was missing some things. Some of the `<script>` tags needed `/`'s.

This was the code that I used:

```
<script>
 
var NepPlayer = "#player";     
// ID of html element where emulator will be inserted
 
var NepEmu = "nes";         
// Platform select
 
var NepLang = "en";
// Option "en,rus,ptBR,ja"
// Interface language of emulator. EN by default
 
var gameUrl = "https://neptunjs.xyz/roms/nes/Super Mario Bros (W) [!].zip"; // Game Url 
</script>
 
<script src="https://mem.neptunjs.com/njs/njsLoader.js" type="text/javascript"> //NeptunJS lib
</script>
<div id="player"></div>
```